# Delete one node/element from a set of similar nodes

Tags: c#, xml, removechild

Here's what I need to do:
sample XML (not sure if it displays right here)

```
 <Tags>
 <Tag ID="0" UserTotal="1" AllowMultipleSelect="1">
  <Name>BaseSamples</Name> 
  <Sample ID="546" Count="1">Sample1 </Sample> 
  <Sample ID="135" Count="1">Sample99</Sample> 
  <Sample ID="544" Count="1">Sample2</Sample> 
  <Sample ID="5818" Count="1">Sample45</Sample> 
  </Tag>
  </Tags>
```

I want to delete:

```
<Sample ID="135" Count="1">Sample99</Sample>
```

and pass the XML back as:

```
 <Tags>
 <Tag ID="0" UserTotal="1" AllowMultipleSelect="1">
  <Name>BaseSamples</Name> 
  <Sample ID="546" Count="1">Sample1 </Sample>   
  <Sample ID="544" Count="1">Sample2</Sample> 
  <Sample ID="5818" Count="1">Sample45</Sample> 
  </Tag>
  </Tags>
```

Any help/tips will be appreciated. I will be knowing the incoming Sample 'ID' attribute, as well as the 'SampleName' (element's CDATA).

Comment: Amy, please don't put strings like "C#" in your title if you're just trying to categorize your question. That's what tags are for, and you've already got the C# tag on the question.

Comment: thanks for the input.. This was the first time I was trying this forum, so kind of messed it up I guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this in C#

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load("XMLFile.xml");     
 XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Tags/Tag/Sample[@ID='135']");
 XmlNode parentNode = node.ParentNode;
 if (node != null) {
   parentNode.RemoveChild(node);
 }
 xmlDoc.Save("NewXMLFileName.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing this stylesheet against the XML will produce the desired ouptut:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <!--identity template copies all content forward -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--empty template will prevent this element from being copied forward-->
    <xsl:template match="Sample[@ID='135']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I have to write C# code for this. Is there a way to use the 'RemoveChild()' method to remove this node? I researched a little, using the XmlNode object along with removeChild() methods (while checking against /Sample[@ID='135'] ).. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You could have C# code that invokes the XSLT... I'm not a C# developer, so I can't provide the exact code snippet to use RemoveChild(). However, the XPATH that you provided is incorrect, which might be why it isn't working for you.  It should be `/Tags/Tag/Sample[@ID='135']`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer Mads Hansen, it was very helpful!!! 
Thanks to all others too! 
Yes my path was wrong.
Your code works, however in my case, doing 'save' was causing an error now. 
I was using the same string to save the information (not a newfile.xml, as you mentioned in the example answer). Perhaps that was causing me trouble, Here is what I did to solve this new issue:

```
 XmlDocument workingDocument = new XmlDocument();  
 workingDocument.LoadXml(sampleInfo); //sampleInfo comes in as a string.
 int SampleID = SampleID;  //the SampleID comes in as an int.   

 XmlNode currentNode;
 XmlNode parentNode;  
 // workingDocument.RemoveChild(workingDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Tags/Tag/Sample[@ID=SampleID]"));
  if (workingDocument.DocumentElement.HasChildNodes)
   {                              
                           //This won't work:   currentNode = workingDocument.RemoveChild(workingDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Sample[@ID=" + SampleID + "]"));
                          currentNode = workingDocument.SelectSingleNode("Tags/Tag/Sample[@ID=" + SampleID + "]");
                          parentNode = currentNode.ParentNode;
                          if (currentNode != null)
                          {
                              parentNode.RemoveChild(currentNode);
                          }                              


                // workingDocument.Save(sampleInfo);

                           sampleInfo = workingDocument.InnerXml.ToString();
}
```